# IMPORTRANGE + extra column does not behave as table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am creating a sheet for our homebrew RPG.
I'm importing a range of data (spell list) in the character sheet, via IMPORTRANGE.

I'm using a True/False checkbox to add the line to a table in another sheet.

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(DataSorts!$A$3:$Q$1001;"select " &IF($E$15;"C";"B")& " where (A=TRUE)");"")
```

I want to use the imported datas as a table WITH the checkboxes column, so my players could filter or classify their data. The checkboxes need not to be on the original spell list so any player could have their own selected ones.

I need to Import the data as the original spell list is expanding and I need to update it regularly.

However, if I update my original sheet comporting the speel list, any add or substract of row will break the checkbox usage (because they wont move where the imported data will, thus the spells selected won't stay the same).

How can I link these 2 parameters ?

Answer (score -1):

Use an index to keep the order in the imported data SS, and then perform the combined VLOOKUP+IMPORTRANGE.