# VLOOKUP + QUERY + IMPORTRANGE > import all lines with condition true

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

> Following this question [IMPORTRANGE + extra column does not behave as table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73139331/importrange-extra-column-does-not-behave-as-table), I read about the VLOOKUP+QUERY+IMPORTRANGE
> other questions and decided it was a good way to use an index to store
> lines without breaking the logic of the other sheets.

I am using a combined VLOOKUP + IMPORTRANGE to copy original data to a viewer sheet. I have the lines imported correctly, matching their index, but I needed the condition that only checked lines in the original data sheet should be imported to the viewer SS.
The Viewer SS then presents a copy of the datas and will also use checkboxes to select and show some data in another sheet. Thus, I needed the index to keep the order in the table and not mess this final step.

This shows the lines with matching index ( I do not have the checked condition): `=IFERROR(arrayformula(VLOOKUP($A$3:$A$1001;IMPORTRANGE($A$1;"DataSorts!B2:S1000");2;false));"")`

This gets only the lines where a checkbox (Col1) is checked in the original data sheet :
`QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(A1;I1);"select Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10 where Col1='TRUE'";1)`

You can find an exemple of the logic here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qBGkWETY2fcUks2gsPgeRSaG_RuFkOmik0_WKNs1nUQ/edit?usp=sharing

Be aware that I put the original data example in the same SS, for simplicity. I'll use an IMPORTRANGE in the QUERY or the VLOOKUP to get the real datas, whichever is the best solution.

Thanks a lot for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A10; 
 QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1qBGkWETY2fcUks2gsPgeRSaG_RuFkOmik0_WKNs1nUQ"; "Data (Edit)!A2:D10")}; 
 "select Col2,Col1,Col3,Col4 where Col1=TRUE"; ); {3\ 4}; )))
```

[image]

Comment: It is working in this sheet but not in my main.
Could you detail the Query formula ? Thanks !

Comment: This is what I'm working on : https://i.postimg.cc/V68jQZty/image-2022-08-02-133433834.png

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A1000; 
 QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(A1; I1)}; 
 "select Col2,Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14 where Col1=TRUE"; ); {3\ 4}; )))`

Comment: @BattlePoap first you need to run `=IMPORTRANGE(A1; I1)` and allow access. then, if your spreadsheets are connected try the full formula

Comment: Yes the spreadsheets are connected, the importrange formula is working on its own.
I have this issue where the first lines are not showing :
https://i.postimg.cc/gkcN73rJ/image-2022-08-03-100610033.png

I used the complete formula: 
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A1000; 
 QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(A1; I1)}; 
 "select Col2,Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14 where Col1=TRUE"; true); {3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 11\ 12\ 13\ 14}; )))`

Comment: And this is the main sheet where all the checkboxes are checked but the lines wont be applied https://i.postimg.cc/Zn3FgkQt/image-2022-08-03-114230484.png