# QUERY + IMPORTRANGE : Did I reached a limit of 999 rows?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Issue with an incomplete import in google sheet

Following this thread :
[VLOOKUP + QUERY + IMPORTRANGE > import all lines with condition true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73210370/vlookup-query-importrange-import-all-lines-with-condition-true)

I have a list of spells that today exceeds 1010 items.
The source data is imported in different spreadsheets with the following formula that does work : `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A;  QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(A1; I1)};  "select Col2,Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15 where Col1=TRUE"; ); {3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 11\ 12\ 13\ 14\ 15}; )))`

However, I reach a limit at row A1001 ; the following wont get filled with any data even though the remaining items in the source data followed the query rules.

I import a table of 15 columns, so I was wondering if there was a limit of 15*1000 cells in google sheet and if so, what was the best way of getting the extra rows.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried importing your full range in an auxiliary sheet, and then refer this formula to that sheet in the same workbook? Maybe there's some limitation in the calculations due to importing several times

Comment: If not try removing IFNA and check if it's returning an error

Comment: Tried both.

2) without IFNA I get the #N/A error in all the previousluy blank cells, but not my missing rows

Comment: 1) gives me a formula error using this syntax
`=ARRAYFORMULA((VLOOKUP(A3:A1001; 
 (QUERY({Sheet!A2:O};
 "select Col2,Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15 where Col1=TRUE";); {3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 11\ 12\ 13\ 14\ 15}; ))))`

Where sheet has an IMPORTRANGE in A1 linking to he source data

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting in Sheet 2 the full QUERY:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Sheet1!A1;Sheet1!I1)};  "select Col2,Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15 where Col1=TRUE"; )
```

(PS: I'm guessing your first sheet is called Sheet1, please check it)

And in Sheet1 you can use FILTER:

```
=BYROW(A3:A,LAMBDA(each,IFNA(FILTER(Sheet2!B:O,Sheet2!A:A=each))))
```

Let me know!

Comment: Thanks Martin !

The IMPORT + FILTER is almost functioning.
At least it reproduces the previous behavior.

Here is what I have :

[screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/4d6Q8YB/image.png)

As you can see
1) the import moves the table one cell to the right.  I think I could manage that in the formula above.
2) we still have the same problem, only 1000 rows are imported, but now I have the value error, which is an improvment. It says "value should be a singe line"

Comment: Why do you have empty values in column A from 1001st row and more?

Comment: This is my initial issue. I can't load data past 1000 rows
The empty cells are part of the check to import only rows from sourc that have been "checked"/"true" in the source sheet

Comment: Then I think the issue is probably in Column A, not in the queries or filters. How is that column generated??

Comment: Looking at your picture: are you just trying to sort your data by the second column of your imported range? How about this, try it in a new sheet: =QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Sheet1!A1;Sheet1!I1)};  "select Col2,Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15 where Col1=TRUE order by Col2"; )

Comment: I'll better explain the logic behind all this:

1) source data is a table with a check in B column (true/false). When the row is completed, I manually check it (B=TRUE)

2) completed rows, ie rows that I've checked TRUE are imported, the others are blank (Col1=TRUE in the import QUERY)

3) I sort and hide the blank rows with a Segment (= non-null)

4) still in the imported datas, I have a A column with checkboxes. When set to TRUE, the row is imported in a different sheet (where it will be displayed in another fashion)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251227/discussion-between-martin-and-battlepoap).